# Hibernate 4 custom ID retreival

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, db2

Using Hiberante 4.3 with DB2 10.5.  We have a situation with some of our tables due to a detail that is not worth repeating here.  But we have a workaround, but it involves customizing how we get the database autogenerated key back from DB2.  The standard "SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1" won't work.

So I want to replace that standard bit of kit with my custom workaround for SOME, NOT ALL tables.  I presume there must be some class I can override, or annotation to direct it or something, but I've no idea where to start.  How can I get my hook in to run my workaround?

Comment: ...yeah, we may need that detail.  `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()` not being usable implies you're inserting into a second table (or more than one row, or a couple of other things), which would be more an overall design issue.  If your table(s) is using `GENERATED ALWAYS`, you may be out of luck.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I'll try to cut out the extraneous why then to keep it short.  The detail is that it is a FEDERATED table.  We insert into many tables on database 1, including a federated table from database 2.  But because the federated table is in a different db, IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL does not work.  We have a workaround as I said, but I just need hibernate to issue my workaround INSTEAD OF IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL.  But only on the tables I know are federated.  So I am hoping I can created a custom generation strategy or something to get my hook in.  otherwise it's just like normal IDENTITY.

Comment: ...It looks like it may be possible to do a [function mapping](http://dbaspot.com/ibm-db2/431252-retrieving-identity-column-federated-table.html) for the end-db version, although there are some caveats there (and Hibernate still wouldn't call it, but you could).  Would it be possible to tell Hibernate to connect to whatever other server directly (your web app has two connections/data sources)?  Or [override the `INSERT` statement](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-customsql).  Or have Hibernate generate the id itself.